# Lua execute something stored in tables key value

Tags: lua, lua-table

I want to make a table with specific names as keys and specific functions as values.
The key names represent commands that a user enters and if a key by that name exists, then the program should execute the code stored in that keys value.

So for example, we make a table with keys and functions inside the key value:

```
local t = {
    ["exit"] = quitGame,
    ...,
    ...
}
```

and we also have a function for example:

```
function quitGame()
  print("bye bye")
  os.exit()
end
```

so now we do:

```
userInput = io.read()

for i,v in pairs(t) do
    if userInput == i then
        --now here, how do I actually run the code that is stored in that key value (v)?
    end
end
```

I hope you understand what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a table keyed by value. There's no need to loop to find the key you want. Just look it up directly. Then just call the value you get back.

```
local fun = t[userInput]
if fun then
    fun()
end
```

Comment: That's exactly what I needed. Thanks! One more question though, how do I stop the program from quitting when a function from the table is called? For example if I want the function to print out something and then wait again for the next user input?

Comment: @thee Ultimately that depends on your environment but in a standalone (for example) a loop like `while true do userInput=io.read() ... done` will work.